# LaTeX font in Flutter looks different inside an ElevatedButton

Tags: flutter

Using
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_math_fork
formulas have different font faces when using inside an ElevatedButton (see image below).
I can't find the reason in the code - what could be the problem?

Screenshot for

```
Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("Hello"),
        Math.tex(r'x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}', mathStyle: MathStyle.display, textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 32)),
        SizedBox(height: 10,),
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: ()=> print("sf"),child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Math.tex(r'x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}', mathStyle: MathStyle.display, textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 32
          )),
        )),
      ],
    ),
```

:
[image]

Comment: may be the text style of the button can be issue?

Comment: No, changing it did not help. And you get the result event when you create the flutter-app-template and add my few lines.